# Fetch console login twice

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch from the PokemonAPI but when I console.log my response, it logs twice, and I don't know if that's a problem or not. I'm doing it with Reactjs. My code:

```
const fetchPokemon = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1')
        const pokemon = await res.json()
        console.log(pokemon)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

fetchPokemon()
```

Comment: I guess that means that `fetchPokemon` is called twice. Probably not a problem but unnecessary.

Comment: Use a `useEffect` hook or `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to make API call. *"that's a problem or not"*: That is a problem unless you knowingly wrote code to do that.

Comment: useEffect worked just fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In React functional components API call should be placed inside `useEffect()` function, this will resolve your issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
async function apiCall() {
           const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1')
           const pokemon = await res.json()
           console.log(pokemon)
        }
        apiCall();
    }, []);
```